# How do I detect if I'm connected to two VPNs on MacOS, from the commandline?

Tags: networking, mac, vpn, terminal

Is it possible to detect, from the commandline, on recent MacOS versions, if the system is connected to two VPNs?

I've tried `scutil`, but it seems not to display information useful for this case.

Answer (score 0):

`scutil --nc show` will show all the VPN service status

Comment: Thanks! I've tested it, and it actually asks `Service:`.

Comment: @marcus specify whether you want to check 'Wi-Fi' or 'Ethernet in service'
eg: `scutil --nc show Wi-Fi`